# Changing Windows 'hosts' file in guest OS under Parallels Desktop 6

Tags: mac-osx

I am running Win7 in a Parallels Desktop 6 on Mac.

I would like to modify my Windows hosts file.

When doing this through notepad it says "You don't have permission to save in this location..."

I am logged on as a regular windows user - not as 'local admin'.

- How can I edit the file?
- How can I grant my regular user 'local admin' rights?
- How can change the Windows user to 'admin' ... this option seems to be missing in my windows install...

Does anybody recognize the issue?

Thank you!
J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is to open Parallels in windowed view, so you see a Windows desktop. Open notepad, then hold CTRL+SHIFT and click on the application icon in your task bar. It should open a new window of notepad with admin access that can edit lmhosts.

Comment: Great, that did the trick! Thx. J.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to @Michael Lowman's answer, here a pure Windows solution for the problem. Not being able to edit a system protected file, like `hosts`, is a Windows security measure. In order to open and edit it, you require elevated permissions (administrator rights).

1. Open Notepad.exe **with elevated permissions** (as admin)
2. From Notepad, choose File > Open
3. Select the C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file
4. Edit as you please and save the file

So there is no need to change your user rights. Just right-click the Notepad shortcut and choose "Run as administrator".

Side effect: once you run an application as 'admin' you cannot simply drag files from Explorer into the application. Explorer will *not* run as admin and Windows won't allow this.